# Error Reading ESRI ArcGrid File using GeoTools?

Tags: geotools, esri-grid-format

I have a raster file in ESRI ArcGrid format (e.g. hdr.adf). I would like to run some analysis using GeoTools. I've never used the coverage classes before and I'm having a few problems out of the gates.

I can instantiate the AIGReader just fine and I get the correct values when I check the bounds. Example:

```
    BaseGDALGridCoverage2DReader reader = new AIGReader(file);

    System.out.println(reader.getSource());
    for (String coverage : reader.getGridCoverageNames()){
        System.out.println(coverage);
    }
    System.out.println(reader.getOriginalEnvelope());
    System.out.println(reader.getOriginalGridRange());
    System.out.println(reader.getCoordinateReferenceSystem());
```

This is the stdout:

```
   Jan 06, 2015 6:38:09 PM it.geosolutions.imageio.gdalframework.GDALUtilities loadGDAL
   INFO: GDAL Native Library loaded (version: 1.11.1)
   Jan 06, 2015 6:38:09 PM org.geotools.coverageio.gdal.BaseGDALGridCoverage2DReader setCoverageProperties
   INFO: crs not found, proceeding with default crs
   K:\Landscan\LandScan_Archive_2000_2012\LandScan2000\lspop2000\hdr.adf
   geotools_coverage
   GeneralEnvelope[(-180.0, -90.0), (179.99999999999858, 85.99999999999929)]
   GridEnvelope2D[0..43199, 0..21119]
   LOCAL_CS["Wildcard 2D cartesian plane in metric unit",
     LOCAL_DATUM["Unknown", 0],
     UNIT["m", 1.0],
     AXIS["x", EAST],
     AXIS["y", NORTH],
     AUTHORITY["EPSG","404000"]]
```

When I call the BaseGDALGridCoverage2DReader.read() method, I get a null pointer exception:

```
    GridCoverage2D gc = (GridCoverage2D) reader.read(null);
```

The read method throws the following Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.geotools.coverageio.RasterLayerRequest.setBaseParameters(RasterLayerRequest.java:902)
    at org.geotools.coverageio.RasterLayerRequest.<init>(RasterLayerRequest.java:206)
    at org.geotools.coverageio.BaseGridCoverage2DReader.read(BaseGridCoverage2DReader.java:400)
```

I tried passing in an array of GeneralParameterValue but I still get a null pointer exception. Example:

```
    ParameterValue<OverviewPolicy> policy = AbstractGridFormat.OVERVIEW_POLICY.createValue();
    policy.setValue(OverviewPolicy.IGNORE);
    ParameterValue<String> gridsize = AbstractGridFormat.SUGGESTED_TILE_SIZE.createValue();
    ParameterValue<Boolean> useJaiRead = AbstractGridFormat.USE_JAI_IMAGEREAD.createValue();
    useJaiRead.setValue(true);

    reader.read(new GeneralParameterValue[]{policy, gridsize, useJaiRead});
```

I'm using Java 1.6 so I'm stuck with GeoTools 10.8.

Any suggestions?

**UPDATE**

QGIS and GDAL can open the file just file. Here's a rendering from QGIS.

[image: QGIS]

Here's the output from gdalinfo. As you can see the projection is not set. I hope this isn't the cause. If it is, is there a way to tell the reader which projection to use?

```
Driver: AIG/Arc/Info Binary Grid
Files: K:\Landscan\LandScan_Archive_2000_2012\LandScan2000\lspop2000
       K:\Landscan\LandScan_Archive_2000_2012\LandScan2000\lspop2000.aux.xml
       K:\Landscan\LandScan_Archive_2000_2012\LandScan2000\lspop2000\dblbnd.adf
       K:\Landscan\LandScan_Archive_2000_2012\LandScan2000\lspop2000\hdr.adf
       K:\Landscan\LandScan_Archive_2000_2012\LandScan2000\lspop2000\log
       K:\Landscan\LandScan_Archive_2000_2012\LandScan2000\lspop2000\metadata.xml
       K:\Landscan\LandScan_Archive_2000_2012\LandScan2000\lspop2000\sta.adf
       K:\Landscan\LandScan_Archive_2000_2012\LandScan2000\lspop2000\vat.adf
       K:\Landscan\LandScan_Archive_2000_2012\LandScan2000\lspop2000\w001001.adf
       K:\Landscan\LandScan_Archive_2000_2012\LandScan2000\lspop2000\w001001x.adf
Size is 43200, 21120
Coordinate System is `'
Origin = (-180.000000000000000,85.999999999999289)
Pixel Size = (0.008333333333333,-0.008333333333333)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  86.0000000)
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -90.0000000)
Upper Right ( 180.0000000,  86.0000000)
Lower Right ( 180.0000000, -90.0000000)
Center      (  -0.0000000,  -2.0000000)
Band 1 Block=256x4 Type=Int32, ColorInterp=Undefined
  Description = lspop2000
  Min=0.000 Max=159004.000
  Minimum=0.000, Maximum=35453.000, Mean=14.586, StdDev=221.326
  NoData Value=-2147483647
  Metadata:
    LAYER_TYPE=athematic
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=35453
    STATISTICS_MEAN=14.58631887449
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=221.32624697214
```

Comment: Is it possible that you've 'broken' the GRID by copying it using a filesystem manager (like explorer)?

Comment: I don't think so. I can view the data with QGIS and gdal apps like gdalinfo and gdal_translate work just fine.

Comment: Perhaps use Gdal_Translate to convert to GeoTiff then read from the Tiff, just remember to delete the temp file when you're finished.

Comment: Not a bad idea. For my own sanity, can you confirm that I'm calling the reader correctly?

Comment: I don't know, I don't use Java or GeoTools. I do however have a lot of experience with Esri GRID and GDAL.

Comment: can you turn logging up to DEBUG and see if anything useful pops up?

Comment: It might be that you have no projection defined for the file (or atleast GeoTools can't see one) - what does gdalinfo say?

Comment: @iant I have updated the question with an output from gdalinfo. I'll try to find a way to crank up the DEBUG level too.

Answer (score 1):

While this doesn't actually help you I can read a Grid file using the following code:

```
    File raster = new File("../../data/nzdem/nzdem500/hdr.adf");

    AbstractGridFormat format = GridFormatFinder.findFormat(raster);
    AbstractGridCoverage2DReader reader = format.getReader(raster);
    GridCoverage2D cov;
    try {
        cov = reader.read(null);
    } catch (IOException giveUp) {
        throw new RuntimeException(giveUp);
    }
```

I get the following log file notes:

> Jan 07, 2015 10:06:10 AM
>   it.geosolutions.imageio.gdalframework.GDALUtilities loadGDAL INFO:
>   GDAL Native Library loaded (version: 1.9.2)
>
> Jan 07, 2015 10:06:10 AM
>   org.geotools.coverageio.gdal.BaseGDALGridCoverage2DReader
>   setCoverageProperties
>
> INFO: crs not found, proceeding with default crs
>
> Error: Could not find mediaLib accelerator wrapper classes. Continuing
>   in pure Java mode. Occurs in: com.sun.media.jai.mlib.MediaLibAccessor

Comment: Thanks Ian. Unfortunately, with this more generic approach, the GridFormatFinder.findFormat() is throwing an error. I have removed all the drivers I don't need from my project so I'm getting a "NoClassDefFoundError: it/geosolutions/imageio/plugins/idrisi/IDRISIImageReaderSpi"

Comment: I don't think you can do that

Comment: I can't do what exactly? Prune unused jars? Call the AIGReader directly?

Comment: prune the unused jars - there are compiled references to them in the code base.

Comment: If you use the GridFormatFinder it looks like you need all the jars. However, you can bypass the GridFormatFinder and call a reader directly. In this case you do not need all the jars. I have verified this with the GeoTiffReader.

Comment: But what if you are using a gdal format like arcgrid?